# Hide HTML Rows Based on User Input

Tags: html, html-table

I'm building a table of simulated basketball statistics and I would like for users to be able to set a minimum games played requirement. Here's what I've got so far cobbled together from various vaguely similar questions I found here:

```
<form> 
<p>Minimum Games Played?</p> 
<input type="number" name="gamesnumber"><br> 
</form>

function view(){
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("games")
 for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  if(x[i].value < gamesnumber){
   x[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
  }else{
   x[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "collapse";
  }
 }
}
</script>

<html>
<head><title>Per Game Stats</title></head>
<body background="" bgcolor=#FFFFFF text="#000000" link=#000000 vlink=#000000>
<tr><td align="center"><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" width="100%"><div align="center"><b><u>Player Statistics</u></b></div></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" width="100%"><div align="center"><center><table border="0">
<thead><tr><th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><b><u>ID</u></b></font></th>
<th width="100" bgcolor=#E85757 align="left"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>Team</b></u></font></th>
<th width="150" bgcolor=#E85757 align="left"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>Name</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>Pos</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>G</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>M</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>P</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>R</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>A</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>S</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>B</b></u></font></th>
<th width="30" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>T</b></u></font></th>
<th width="50" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>FG%</b></u></font></th>
<th width="50" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>FT%</b></u></font></th>
<th width="50" bgcolor=#E85757 align="center"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF"><u><b>3P%</b></u></font></th></thead><tbody>
<tr><td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">503</font></td>
<td width="150" align="left"><font size="2"><a href="./rosters/roster6.htm">Washington Bullets</a></font></td>
<td width="150" align="left"><font size="2"><a href="./players/player503.htm">Aaron Holiday</a></font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">PG</font></td>
<td class="games" width="30" align="center"><font size="2">40</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">12.2</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">4.2</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">1.3</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">2.7</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.4</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.1</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">1.1</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.407</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.692</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.489</font></td>
<tr><td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">461</font></td>
<td width="150" align="left"><font size="2"><a href="./rosters/roster26.htm">Portland Trailblazers</a></font></td>
<td width="150" align="left"><font size="2"><a href="./players/player461.htm">Ajdin Penava</a></font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">C</font></td>
<td class="games" align="center"><font size="2">82</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">27.6</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">6.6</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">8.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">1.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.5</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.8</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.8</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.414</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.841</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.391</font></td>
<tr><td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">203</font></td>
<td width="150" align="left"><font size="2"><a href="./rosters/roster23.htm">Golden State Warriors</a></font></td>
<td width="150" align="left"><font size="2"><a href="./players/player203.htm">Alex Abdul-Wahad</a></font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">SG</font></td>
<td class="games" width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="30" align="center"><font size="2">0.0</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.000</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.000</font></td>
<td width="50" align="center"><font size="2">.000</font></td>
</tbody></table></center></div></td></tr>
</body>
</html>
```

But entering values in the form does nothing. Am I on the right track? Something else entirely?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, your form and script tags must be inside body tag.
Your elements with class games are td tags, so this tags don't have a value property, instead they have innerText property,
next of it, you're not calling view function anywhere.
Change your code to this (I'm writing only the code you must change):

```
<form> 
<p>Minimum Games Played?</p> 
<input type="number" name="gamesnumber" id="gamesnumber"><br> 
</form>
```

And this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function view(){
var gamesnumber = document.getElementById("gamesnumber").value || 0; //this is valid because is a textinput, we add 0 as default value
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("games");
 for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  if(x[i].innerText < gamesnumber){
   x[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
  }else{
   x[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "collapse";
  }
 }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //we add this event listener because your input element tecnically doesn't exist until page is loaded
    var input_games = document.getElementById("gamesnumber");
    input_games.addEventListener("input", view); //we call this function every time input value changes

});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help! When I c/p this it doesn't seem to do anything though, I can change the input and nothing happens. Do I need to include something somewhere else?

Comment: yeah, you should add the `item-row` class to each row you want to make visible/invisible, check also your html table tree, some tr are not closed  and maybe this can make the program has an unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="number" name="gamesnumber" onchange="view()"><br>
```

> Have a onchange event call in your input, so as soon as you enter
>   something in the textbox, the defined(view) function will be called

Also, change your view() function to hide the corresponding row when the condition is matched.

Changed function :

```
function view(){
 var gamesnumber = document.getElementsByName("gamesnumber")[0].value;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("games")
 for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  if(x[i].innerText < gamesnumber){
   x[i].parentElement.style.visibility = "visible";
  }else{
   x[i].parentElement.style.visibility = "collapse";
  }
 }
}
```

**Edit :** 
As this is a `onchange()` event, after typing you should click somewhere or press tab to trigger the function, if you want on typing you can use `onblur` or `onkeyup()` too.

Refer this more more information on such trigger events : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Comment: thanks for the help! when i try this the table flickers but then goes back to normal - it happens very quickly but it looks like the script collapses the relevant rows and then makes them visible again. I even tried taking the = "visible" part out entirely but they still pop back. Any thoughts?

Comment: I thought the expectation was when you type any number, and if the inputNumber is < the games, the row stays and if is > the games then it collapses. Correct ? You want to remove them completely from the html ? or toggle between hide/show ?

Comment: Check this code, and let me know if it works as per your requirement or not : https://jsfiddle.net/ef94gmvn/

It is the complete code, I did not want to edit my answer with a long code again.

Comment: yes, that's the expectation i was going for! and thanks for the example, not sure what i was doing wrong but it's working now. thanks again!